# How to use RxJava combineLatest operator with more than 9 observables

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm using RxJava and I want to combine 12 different observables using the operator `combineLatest`.

I saw a function prototype that takes a list of observables and an implementation of `FuncN` but I'm not sure how to do this, I'm having trouble implementing the `call` method.

Can someone show me an example?

Comment: Please, format your code and functions using `\`\``

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#combineLatest(java.util.List,%20rx.functions.FuncN)) that takes a `List` of observables. Here's an example on how to use it:

```
List<Observable<?>> list = Arrays.asList(Observable.just(1), Observable.just("2"));
Observable.combineLatest(list, new FuncN<String>() {
    @Override
    public String call(Object... args) {
        String concat = "";
        for (Object value : args) {
            if (value instanceof Integer) {
                concat += (Integer) value;
            } else if (value instanceof String) {
                concat += (String) value;
            }
        }
        return concat;
    }
});
```

Comment: How do I do if I have different observable types? (eg. Observable<A>, Obsevable<B>, etc)

Comment: @user3762200 the values inside `args` will have the same order as in the `list`. You can either rely on this order or check for each value's type. depending on your use case. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me

Comment: How is the `FuncN<String>()` defined? I can't seem to invoke this.

Answer (score 6):

Yo expand on that answer, I am using it to read multiple characteristics at once, it can be done like so:

```
connectionObservable
                .flatMap((Func1<RxBleConnection, Observable<?>>) rxBleConnection -> {
                    List<Observable<?>> list1 = Arrays.asList(
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),
                            rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...));
                    return Observable.combineLatest(list1, args -> {
                       Object o =  doSomethingWithResults(args);
                        return o;
                    });
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnUnsubscribe(this::clearConnectionSubscription)
                .subscribe(retVal -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "result:" + retVal.toString());
                    Log.w(TAG, "SUCCESS");
                    triggerDisconnect();

                }, MyActivity.this::onReadFailure);
    }
```

Comments if you have suggestions on how to improve this process.

Comment: What happens when one of those characteristics throw an onError?

Comment: It goes to onReadFailure, in my case I wanna throw out the whole reading if one fails so it works for me.

Comment: Replace each line `rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...),` with `rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID...).onErrorResumeNext { bytes -> Observable.just(new byte[0])) },` essentially you are returning an empty byte array if a certain characteristic is not found. code will continue

Answer (score 2):

**RxKotlin** supports upto 9 opertators in parameters in combineLatest() method but to use more than 9 parameters
means to pass unlimited dynamic custom object arraylist you can use it as below:

> First Let me give you simple example with only two parameters with
>   custom data types

```
val name = Observable.just("MyName")
val age = Observable.just(25)
Observables.combineLatest(name, age) { n, a -> "$n - age:${a}" }
                .subscribe({
                    Log.d("combineLatest", "onNext - ${it}")
                })
```

> Now what if i want to pass multiple parameters in combineLatest? Then
>   your answer is below: (i have used custom data types, so someone's
>   custom problem can also be solved here)

```
val myList = arrayOf(Observable.just("MyName"),
                Observable.just(2),
                Observable.just(3.55),
                Observable.just("My Another String"),
                Observable.just(5),
                Observable.just(6),
                Observable.just(7),
                Observable.just(8),
                Observable.just(9),
                Observable.just(10),
                Observable.just(11),
                Observable.just(12),
                Observable.just(13),
                Observable.just(14),
                Observable.just(15))

Observable.combineLatest(myList, {
    val a = it[0] as String
    val b = it[1] as Int
    val c = it[2] as Float
    val d = it[3] as String
    val e = it[4] as Int
    val f = it[5] as Int
    val g = it[6] as Int
    val h = it[7] as Int
    val i = it[8] as Int
    val j = it[9] as Int
    val k = it[10] as Int
    val l = it[11] as Int
    val m = it[12] as Int
    "$a - age:${b}" })
        .subscribe({
            Log.d("combineLatest", "onNext - ${it}")
        })
```

Comment: What do you do about the unchecked casting? If all my observables in my list are the same I know what the type is, but it still gives a warning for an unchecked cast

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple extension function for RxKotlin if you have 10 sources for `combineLatest`. You can easily create similar functions for more sources or adapt this to work with plain RxJava.

```kotlin
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.rxkotlin.Observables

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST", "unused")
inline fun <T1 : Any, T2 : Any, T3 : Any, T4 : Any, T5 : Any, T6 : Any, T7 : Any, T8 : Any, T9 : Any, T10 : Any, R : Any> Observables.combineLatest(
    source1: Observable<T1>, source2: Observable<T2>,
    source3: Observable<T3>, source4: Observable<T4>,
    source5: Observable<T5>, source6: Observable<T6>,
    source7: Observable<T7>, source8: Observable<T8>,
    source9: Observable<T9>, source10: Observable<T10>,
    crossinline combineFunction: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10) -> R
): Observable<R> =
    Observable.combineLatest(arrayOf(source1, source2, source3, source4, source5, source6, source7, source8, source9, source10)) {
        combineFunction(
            it[0] as T1,
            it[1] as T2,
            it[2] as T3,
            it[3] as T4,
            it[4] as T5,
            it[5] as T6,
            it[6] as T7,
            it[7] as T8,
            it[8] as T9,
            it[9] as T10
        )
    }
```

Note: I've created this as an extension function to stay consistent with how `combineLatest` function calls look like for less than 10 sources (`Observables.combineLatest(...)`). That way I don't have to think about which `combineLatest` version I need for what number of parameters. Technically there is no need to make it an extension function.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Egor Neliuba's answer, you can aggregate all the results inside a container object, and then use it as you will inside the subscribe clause:

```
 List<Observable<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(mCreateMarkupFlowManager.getFlowState());
    list.add(mCreateIssueFlowStateManager.getIssueFlowState());
    list.add(mViewerStateManager.getMarkupLoadingProgressChanges());
    list.add(mViewerStateManager.getIssueLoadingProgressChanges());
    list.add(mMeasurementFlowStateManager.getFlowState());
    list.add(mViewerStateManager.isSheetLoaded());
    list.add(mProjectDataManager.isCreateFieldIssueEnabledForCurrentProject().distinctUntilChanged());
    list.add(mViewerStateManager.getMarkupViewMode());
    list.add(mViewerStateManager.isFirstPerson());
    list.add(mProjectDataManager.isCreateRfiEnabledForCurrentProject().distinctUntilChanged());
    list.add(mCreateRfiFlowStateManager.getRfiFlowState());

    attachSubscription(Observable.combineLatest(list, args -> {
                Holder holder = new Holder();
                holder.setFirst((String) args[0]);
                holder.setSecond((Integer) args[1]);
                holder.setThird((Boolean) args[2]);
                holder.setFourth((Boolean) args[3]);
                holder.setFifth((String) args[4]);
                holder.setSixth((Boolean) args[5]);
                holder.setSeventh((Boolean) args[6]);
                holder.setEighth((Boolean) args[7]);
                holder.setNinth((Boolean) args[8]);
                holder.setTenth((Boolean) args[9]);
                holder.setEleventh((String) args[10]);
                return holder;
            })
                    .filter(holder -> Util.isTrue(holder.sixth))
                    .compose(Util.applySchedulers())
                    .subscribe(holder -> {
                        if (isViewAttached()) {
                            String createMarkupState = holder.first;
                            Integer createIssueState = holder.second;
                            boolean markupsLoadingFinished = holder.third;
                            boolean issuesLoadingFinished = holder.fourth;
                            boolean loadingFinished = markupsLoadingFinished && issuesLoadingFinished;
                            String measurementState = holder.fifth;
                            boolean isMarkupLockMode = holder.eighth;

                            boolean showCreateMarkupButton = shouldShowCreateMarkupButton();
                            boolean showCreateMeasureButton = shouldShowMeasureButton();
                            boolean showCreateFieldIssueButton = holder.seventh;
                            boolean isFirstPersonEnabled = holder.ninth;
                            Boolean showCreateRfiButton = holder.tenth;
                            String rfiFlowState = holder.eleventh;


                        }
                    })
    );


public class Holder {


public String first;
public Integer second;
public Boolean third;
public Boolean fourth;
public String fifth;
public Boolean sixth;
public Boolean seventh;
public Boolean eighth;
public Boolean ninth;
public Boolean tenth;
public String eleventh;

public void setEleventh(String eleventh) {
    this.eleventh = eleventh;
}


public void setFirst(String first) {
    this.first = first;
}


public void setSecond(Integer second) {
    this.second = second;
}


public void setThird(Boolean third) {
    this.third = third;
}


public void setFourth(Boolean fourth) {
    this.fourth = fourth;
}


public void setFifth(String fifth) {
    this.fifth = fifth;
}


public void setSixth(Boolean sixth) {
    this.sixth = sixth;
}


public void setSeventh(Boolean seventh) {
    this.seventh = seventh;
}


public void setEighth(Boolean eighth) {
    this.eighth = eighth;
}


public void setNinth(Boolean ninth) {
    this.ninth = ninth;
}


public void setTenth(Boolean tenth) {
    this.tenth = tenth;
}


public Holder() {}

}
```