# How to use RxJava2 combineLatest with a list of observables in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I know how to do this in [RxJava 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811923/how-to-use-rxjava-combinelatest-operator-with-more-than-9-observables).

And I know how [RxKotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725749/observable-combinelatest-type-inference-in-kotlin) helps with similar issues.

But it seems that RxKotlin.Observables doesn't have this helper function for the list overload and I cannot figure it out. How would you do this?

Comment: It's an extension function on `Iterable<Observable<T>>`. Do `listOfObservables.combineLatest { ... }`

Comment: That was it, thanks. You could write an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most static functions in RxJava are extension functions in RxKotlin. This particular function is an extension on `Iterable<Observable<T>>`. You can call it like this:

```
listOfObservables.combineLatest { ... }
```

Answer (score 6):

for RxJava 2 this could be done in this way

```
    val list = Arrays.asList(
            remoteRepository.getHospitals(),
            remoteRepository.getQuestionCategories(),
            remoteRepository.getQuestions(),

    )


    return Observable.combineLatest(list) {

        val hospitals = it[0] as List<Hospital>

        val questionCategories = it[1] as List<QuestionCategory>
        val questions = it[2] as List<Question>


        localRepository.insertHospitals(hospitals)
        localRepository.insertQuestionCategories(questionCategories)
        localRepository.insertQuestions(questions)


        if (hospitals.isNotEmpty())
            Constants.STATUS_OK
        else
            Constants.STATUS_ERROR

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val list = Arrays.asList(Observable.just(1), Observable.just("2"))
Observable.combineLatest(list, object : FuncN<String>() {
    fun call(vararg args: Any): String {
        var concat = ""
        for (value in args) {
            if (value is Int) {
                concat += value
            } else if (value is String) {
                concat += value
            }
        }
        return concat
    }
})
```

Observable.just(1), Observable.just("2") can be replaced with list of observable and login inside call fun will also changed as per requirements.