# How to use combineLatest with multiple sources

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-kotlin

I am using the RXKotlin combineLatest and I have a multiple source. but I am calling this like

```
Observables.combineLatest(source1, source2)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        {
            val first = it.first
            val second = it.second
        },
        {

        }
    )
```

and

```
Observables.combineLatest(source3, source4)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        {
            val first = it.first
            val second = it.second
        },
        {

        }
    )
```

now I just want to ask on how to use the combineLatest to my sources only once.

like this.

```
Observables.combineLatest(source1, source2, source3, source4)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        {
            val first = it.first
            val second = it.second
            val third = it.third
            val fourth = it.fourth
            //...
        },
        {

        }
    )
```

I am always using this combineLatest but only with three parameters and I really don't know how or what should I do when I add more parameters to it.

Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Since my question marked as duplicate, I just want to clarify if the `Observables` from rxkotlin is the same to `Observable` from rxjava? because the source did not solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: hi i have given answer to your question in kotlin. please refer answer by "android". please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55438361/7326905